# Obtaining historical total crypto Market cap data through an API

Tags: cryptocurrency, coinmarketcap, coingecko

I have been searching for a way to retrieve historical and current total crypto market data through an API without paying a fortune. My end goal is to be able to calculate coin dominance for any coin I am interested in.

Coingecko only seems to provide current market information through /global , i see that coinmarketcap has the option for historical market cap data for a single date (?) and this requires a $300 monthly sub. Am I missing anything?